# How to map a list of one type to a list of another type in modern c++ using algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm

Seems like everybody agrees that you need to avoid usage of raw loops e.g.

```cpp
for (...)
{
   ...
}
```

the same is applied to `while`...

I'm looking for a best way to accomplish a mapping from `std::list<type_a>` to `std::list<type_b>` and follow this practice. My first guess is that I need to use standard algorithms. I would expect something like:

```cpp
std::list<type_a> list_a= {...};
std::list<type_b> list_b= some_algorithms<type_b>(list_a);
```

What should I choose and how final solution will look like?
I strive to have the most elegant and efficient solution possible.

Comment: `std::transform` + `std::back_inserter`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do this with std::transform too.

```
// convert list function
template<typename to_type, typename from_type>
std::list<to_type> convert_list(const std::list<from_type>& from_list)
{
    std::list<to_type> to_list{ from_list.size() };
    std::transform(from_list.cbegin(), from_list.cend(), to_list.begin(), [](const from_type& value) { return convert<to_type>(value); });
    return to_list;
}
```

Comment: What do you think about using std::back_inserter here? What is better - reserving the new list in advance or constructing it on the go?

Comment: It totally depends on the actual implementation of std::list. My gut feeling is pre-allocation since we can be sure it doesn't have to grow internally (reallocating memory) when adding new items to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think that any solution will have some kind of loop in there (even if it is hidden inside some standard library algorithm).

I took your line
std::list<type_b> list_b= some_algorithms<type_b>(list_a);
As a basis and came up with this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include <string>

// in general converting items is just typecasting them
template<typename to_type, typename from_type>
to_type convert(const from_type& value)
{
    return static_cast<to_type>(value);
}

// add specializations for conversion when needed, in this case int to std::string
template<>
std::string convert(const int& value)
{
    return std::to_string(value);
}

// convert list function
template<typename to_type, typename from_type>
std::list<to_type> convert_list(const std::list<from_type>& from_list)
{
    std::list<to_type> to_list;

    for (const auto& value : from_list)
    {
        to_list.push_back(convert<to_type>(value));
    }

    return to_list;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> values{ 0,1,42 };
    auto string_values = convert_list<std::string>(values);
}
```

Comment: as per @Evg comment, std::transform is the STL function that already implements somehow your `convert_list`. your one (which it's correct, at least I cannot spot any bug in it) it's quite similar to the "possible implementation" of std::transform suggested by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Very likely, the STL guys did implement it correctly, considering all the corner cases , efficiently and better then I could write it: let's make the most of their job

Comment: @GianPaolo Looks like I have to lookup transform in more detail then ;)